# why closes my python program without fully executing?

Tags: python

I am completely new to programming and started a few days ago with learning Python(v.3.8.8). I wanted to make a small password manager, but with a little secret function(I think that's not important and it would take too much time to describe). Anyways I converted the main.py to a .exe with auto-py-to-exe but every time I wanna execute the .exe I can only enter my Login data and the window instantly closes but in Pycharm everything works totally fine. Does anyone know why?
EDIT: It works now, there was no missing "Input()" or stuff like that, I had a spelling mistake in my code and pycharm ignored it!

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

welcome = input("Login(1), New User (2): ")


def new_user():  # creates a new user and safe the Username and pw in a .txt
    print("The login is just for the safety of your data, everything is stored on your local PC!")
    username = input("Enter a username:")
    password = input("Enter a password:")
    password1 = input("Confirm password:")
    if password == password1:
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        f = Fernet(key)
        f.encypt(b'password')
        file = open(username + ".txt", "w")
        file.write(username + ":" + password)
        #file.close()
        login()  # go to login after everything is safed in the .txt
    else:
        print("Passwords do NOT match!")


def login():  # checks if the entered username and pw match with the .txt content
    login1 = input("Login:")
    login2 = input("Password:")
    file = open(login1 + ".txt", "r")
    pw = file.readline()
    #file.close()
    if pw == login1 + ":" + login2:  # infinte trys to enter the username and pw
        print("Welcome " + login1)
        pwrequest()
    else:  # returns to login() if the pw is incorrect
        print("Incorrect username or password. Please try again")
        login()


def pwrequest():
    q = input("safe new Password(1), show safed passwords(2)")
    if q == "2":
        data()  # show all saved pw
    if q == "1":
        newdata()  # go to data() if the user want to add a new pw or
        # want to acces the hidden part


def data():
    file = open('1.txt', 'r')  # prints all saved passwords
    file_pw = file.read()
    print(file_pw)
    file.close()
    c = input("Press (1) to delete something and press (2) to log out.")
    if c == '1':
        delete()  # delete a pw or acces to hidden part
    if c == '2':
        login()  # simple logout system, probably have to change this to something more intermediate


def newdata():  # safes the data in variables and put it in a .txt file
    company = input("Enter the companys name: ")
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    print(company + username + password + ", is everything correct?")
    a = input("y/n")
    if a == "y":
        file = open("1.txt", "w")
        file.write(
            "Company: " + company + "\n" + "Username: " + username + "\n" + "Password: " + password + "\n" + "\n")
        file.close()
        pwrequest()  # return to pwrequest()
    if a == "n":
        newdata()  # return to newdata() if something is incorrect

    secretWord = "CompanyUsernamePassword"  # define the secret word to finaly acces the hidden part
    if company + username + password == secretWord:
        secrettest()  # go to secrettest() to enter the secret word


def delete():  # just simple code that delete specific content of the pw .txt
    name = input("Please enter the Company, Username and password you wanna delete: ")
    with open("1.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("1.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip("\n") != name:
                f.write(line)


def secrettest():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    f = Fernet(key)
    truepass = f.encrypt(b"Test1234")
    trys = 3
    while trys != 0:  # checks if you entered the correct pw and if not count 2 times
        password = input("Pls enter the password: ")
        d = f.decrypt(truepass)
        if password == d.decode():
            print(truepass)
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong password!")
            trys -= 1
    if trys == 0:
        print("You entered the wrong password to many times!")


if welcome == "1":  # should probably try to move that to the top
    login()

if welcome == "2":  # this too
    new_user()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why do you think it is "not fully executing"? What happened when you tried using a batch file wrapper to run the program and then `pause`? What happened when you tried running the program manually from the command line? What happened when you tried verifying that `welcome` ends up with the value and type you expect? Is there any Python 2.x installation on your system?

Comment: What happened when you tried reading the autopytoexe documentation, or the author's [troubleshooting guide](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/)?

Comment: I assume your python .exe runs in a console window? If so, when the program finishes running, the console window probably closes immediately, because the program is done. If you run your .exe from your Windows Command Prompt, it will probably look more like how it did when you were testing it in PyCharm.

Comment: I think that because as a  .exe it just closes and doesn't jump to the next part of the code but as a .py everything works totally fine. There is no other python version on my PC, only 3.8.8

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why the .exe always closes. I executed the .exe in the windows cmd, and got this error "AttributeError: 'Fernet' object has no attribute 'enrcypt'". I'm kinda sure that this is the part that caused the trouble. I'm just wondering why pycharm just ignored this error...